# How to set numwidth in the grid output of PL/SQL developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I'm running some queries in PL/SQL Developer, and one of the columns in the result has 18-digit numbers. Instead of displaying the entire number in the resulting grid, PL/SQL Developer displays only 15 digits in scientific notation.

I tried to find a way to change this in the preferences of the program, so that I'll see the entire number, just like `set numwidth` does in SQL*Plus. But my search was futile.

How do I change this setting?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out this **is** possible!!!

> Tools -> Preferences -> SQL Window ->
>   Number fields to_char

Comment: Does anybody know, where is this setting in Oracle SQL Developer Studio 4.0?

Comment: Hmm... this had no effect for me

Answer (score 6):

Use to_char, then you get the all the numbers:

```
select to_char ( t.reference_nr), t.reference_nr from rss_ing_cc_imp t
1   95209140353000001009592 9,5209140353E22
2   25546980354901372045601 2,55469803549014E22
3   75203220356000583867347 7,52032203560006E22
4   25546980357904327000017 2,55469803579043E22
5   95209140358000000700337 9,5209140358E22
6   95209140359000000596387 9,5209140359E22
7   25546980361131086003511 2,55469803611311E22
8   25546980361901390031808 2,55469803619014E22
9   85207130362051881964326 8,52071303620519E22
10  95209140363000000634885 9,5209140363E22
11  25546980364131099000436 2,55469803641311E22
12  95209141001000001006196 9,5209141001E22
13  85207131001100892094030 8,52071310011009E22
14  75203221001000590476576 7,52032210010006E22
```

Comment: I guess this is the best you can get. Thank you very much, @RiKl! I've been waiting for an answer for ages :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the column format(Using the same table name as above...)

column reference_nr format 99999999999999999999999999999999

Select reference_nr from rss_ing_cc_imp;

### REFERENCE_NR

```
      95209140353000001009592 
      25546980354901372045601
```

Or ( new session ) which probably is better:

show numwidth

numwidth 10

Select reference_nr from rss_ing_cc_imp;

### REFERENCE_NR

```
 9.5E+22 
 2.6E+22
```

Set numwidth 30

show numwidth

numwidth 30

Select reference_nr from rss_ing_cc_imp;

### REFERENCE_NR

```
   95209140353000001009592 
   25546980354901372045601
```

Comment: Using sqlplus in bash script, my problem was : 
Excepted : 53204024705854
But was : 5,3204E+13
Using : set numwidth 30 solved my probleme.


"set numwidth 30
\nset newpage none
\nset heading off
\nset timing off
\nset echo off
\nset linesize 32767
\nselect xxx from yyy where zzz;"

Answer (score 1):

```
SET sqlformat ansiconsole;
```

This will set the output format for any queries that you run hereafter. There are other sql formats but this is probably the best for your situation.

To revert to what you had earlier, use.

```
SET sqlformat;
```

*This has been verified on SQLDeveloper Version 18.3.0.277, Build 277.2354

Comment: "This" has been verified...  Really? I guess only the first command, not the second. The way to clear the `sqlformat` is to run `SET` without options - not `UNSET` as you wrote. I edited your answer to show the correct command.

Comment: SQL Developer is a complete different client to PL/SQL Developer, which is what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Ilya Kogan, but in PL SQL Dev 13 the Preferences has moved and is now under an little tuner icon in the title bar. Then SQL Window -> Number fields to_char