# How do I convince Oracle SQL Developer to show number in scientific notation?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer version 4.0.3, and I have a number in the order of 1e-13, so it's kind of inconvenient to have it shown as 0.0000000000001...

I couldn't find any option to change this behaviour, what I'd like is something like the opposite of this question, but for Oracle SQL developer:
[How to set numwidth in the grid output of PL/SQL developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063167/how-to-set-numwidth-in-the-grid-output-of-pl-sql-developer)

I just cannot find anything similar, does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#BABIGFBA):

```
to_char(<your number column>, '9.9EEEE')
```

In SQL Developer 4:

[image: SQL Developer window]

I can't see any way to apply a model globally, as suggested by the accepted answer from the question you linked to - the current version of SQL Developer doesn't seem to have 'SQL Window' section under preferences like PL/SQL Developer does. But you probably don't want to apply the model to every number in every result set anyway.

Comment: Just accepted this answer (that I should've accepted long long ago but forgot :P), as this is what I actually end up using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_CHAR(1e-13, '0.9999999999999');`. You need to check for the proper format model to convert the scientific notation into string. I used '.', you could also use 'D' as decimal separator, but it depends on your NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER.

See the different number formats here, http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0300__Conversion-Functions/FormatParameters.htm

**Update** I initially answered the opposite of the requirement, i.e. convert from scientific notation to regular number format. The update is about converting number into scientific notation.

In `SQL Developer`, you would see something like this :

[image]

In `SQL*Plus`, the same `SQL` would convert the number into its scientific notation`.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT to_number('0.0000000000001','0.99999999999999') num FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT to_char(num, '9.9EEEE') num
  5  FROM DATA;

NUM
---------
  1.0E-13

SQL>
```

Without a format,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT to_number('0.0000000000001','0.99999999999999') num FROM dual
  3  )
  4  select num from data;

       NUM
----------
1.0000E-13

SQL>
```

Comment: Aren't you going the wrong way? The OP wants to *see* the scientific notation. You're sort of answering the linked question?

Comment: Aah, you are right. I have updated the answer now. Thanks for pointing it out. Quite unusual requirement though, usually I have seen questions the other way round ;-)