# selecting more than 16 digits result in wrong values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I had this scenario now if i select more then 16 digits in plsql or sql plus i get wrong values:

```
 // the below from plsql
select 12345678901213 from dual
1.23456789101112E16
```

what is the cause of that ? and how to fix that in my procedures ? because I am concatenate more then 16 digits and inserting them in a table.

the below from sqlplus

[image]

Comment: select decimal(12345678901213) from dual... try that one

Comment: @Rams decimal function did work but Round gave correct values select ROUND(12345678901213) from dual

Comment: ok grt...but what is the error you got with decimal... it should work with decimal

Comment: @Rams missing expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SQLPLUS**

Use `SET NUMWIDTH`, example from `sqlplus` command line:

```
SQL> SHOW NUMWIDTH
numwidth 10
SQL> select 12345678901213 from dual;

12345678901213
--------------
    1,2346E+13

SQL> SET NUMWIDTH 20
SQL> select 12345678901213 from dual;

      12345678901213
--------------------
      12345678901213
```

**PL/SQL**

Cast the value to the correct datatype, example (from `sqlplus`):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    my_number NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    select 12345678901213 into my_number from dual;
  5    dbms_output.put_line('Number:'|| my_number);
  6  END;
  7  /
Number:12345678901213
```

Comment: Note that this only works in sql plus , for plsql it doesn't. this link showed how to fixe it for plsql for future reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063167/how-to-set-numwidth-in-the-grid-output-of-pl-sql-developer

Comment: Note, `NUMWIDTH 10` is just the default value in SQL*Plus